# Error occurred during initialization of VM in redhat linux

Tags: java, installation

I downloaded JDK version 1.6.33 (64-bit) and set the environment following [this explanation](http://blog.algoworks.com/archives/210).

When I try

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

it returns
 `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_33/`,

for `echo $PATH`

it shows

`/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_33//bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local /sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin` and

for `echo $CLASSPATH`

it shows `.:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_33//lib/classes.zip`.

When I then try to start any application server I get the following error

> Error occurred during initialization of VM

`java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object`

Please suggest me what i did wrong...

Comment: The double slash might be a problem. Try setting JAVA_HOME to "/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_33" without the trailing "/".

Comment: I tried but by default it took "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to double slashes. Try this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_33
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

This way it will fix the path and will work fine.